# How to test class reading from std::istream?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googletest, googlemock

How to mock `std::istream`? I mean exactly operator `>>`. My tested object reading two numbers from this stream (`std::istream&` is a member of this class). How can I test it? How to read this values in test?

I'd like to test this values or just only read defined in test values to go further in the test.

I use gmock.

Comment: Try `std::stringstream`, a stream that writes to/reads from underlying `std::string`

Comment: @milleniumbu What do you mean? How can I use it in test?

Comment: @peter55555 Create `istringstream` containing values you want to test. Make class read from this stream. Test if everything went as expected.

Comment: How do you construct the istream? Do you have any public function to your class who can set the streambuf for the std::istream?

Comment: @Sam Daniel. In program code I initialize std::istream using boost::asio::streambuf and I pass it to constructor of my tested class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dependency injection to pass an object of class
`std::istringstream` to your object. Create a constructor
 for your class that takes an additional `std::istream &`
 parameter and assign it to your member of this type.
 For example:

```
MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::istream &stream, /* other constructor args */) :
        stream_(stream)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    void my_method()
    {
        int i, j;
        stream_ >>i;
        stream_ >>j;
        ...
    }

private:
    std::istream stream_;
};
```

Then, in your test, simply create `istringstream` object and pass it to constructor:

```
std::istringstream dummyStream("10 20");
MyClass obj(dummyStream, /* other constructor args */);
```

Comment: should be `std::istream & stream_`, otherwise you've sliced whatever gets passed. Luckily the copy constructor of `std::istream` is protected, so `MyClass` can't use it